# Sidebar is not left-aligned - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm practicing with Bootstrap and this element in the sidebar stays at the bottom and not to the right as it should appear.

[image]

I've tried floating it to the right but it doesn't change position.

Here you are the code use it.

I don't know what else I could try so I appreciate your help.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Aprendiendo Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container border">
        <div class="row">


            <header id="header" class="col-12 bg-primary text-white p-2 pl-5">
                <h1>Aprendiendo Bootstrap</h1>
            </header>

            <nav id="menu" class="col-12 bg-secondary text-white">
                <ul class="row w-50">
                    <li class="col">Inicio</li>
                    <li class="col">Página 1</li>
                    <li class="col">Página 2</li>
                    <li class="col">Página 3</li>
                    <li class="col">Contacto</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="content" class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <section id="products" class="col-9 border m-2">
                        <h2>Productos</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="items">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="item col bg-primary m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col bg-warning m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col bg-danger m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row mt-5">
                                <div class="item col bg-primary m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col bg-warning m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col bg-danger m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col bg-success m-2">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row mt-1 justify-content-around">
                                <div class="item col-3 bg-primary">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-3 bg-warning">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                                <div class="item col-3 bg-primary">
                                    Producto
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <aside class="col-3 border">
                        <h2>Barra lateral</h2>

                        <div class="lateral row bg-light align-items-center">

                            <div class="col-4 bg-primary align-self-start">
                                Elemento 1
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 bg-success align-self-center">
                                Elemento 2
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4 bg-warning align-self-end">
                                Elemento 3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aside>

                </div>
            </section>

            <footer class="col-lg-12 bg-info">
                Máster en Bootstrap - Cristina Martínez&copy;
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need more information, please can you ask me.

THANKS!

Comment: I think its because you but the class `m-2` on your section id `#products`, which is also your `col-9`. You added a margin on the left and right of this column now the other column no longer fits and drops to a new line. Use `my-2` to only add margin on the y-axis (top and bottom only)

Comment: Replace m-2 by p-2 if you want space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main div has got a class of m-2 on it. Which means margin is being applied to the div.
If you update your code to this it should work

```
<section id="products" class="col-9">
and
<aside class="col-3">
```

The border on the div and aside might also be pushing the width of each to wide. So try with and without border.

Comment: Thank you!!, you were right. It's because of the m-2 class.

Comment: Great, happy to help. All the best with your studies